# extjs removeFilter() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter

I created a filter and added it to my store

```
checkchange: function(item, checked) {
    if (checked) {
        Ext.getCmp('gridPanel').getStore().removeFilter(item.filter);
    } else {
        Ext.getCmp('gridPanel').getStore().addFilter(item.filter);
    }
}
```

addFilter() works the way I want it to, but removeFilter() does nothing.
clearFilter() works as well, but I want to remove only one filter, not all of them.

Comment: try using `removeAtKey` instead of `removeFilter`

Comment: `removeFilter(item.filter)` doesn't work but `removeFilter(filterId)` works for me. I found the solution after checking the `removeAtKey` method so thanks ;) @Mr_Perfect

Comment: What is `item.filter`?

Answer (score 0):

This will not worked you have pass exact filter object to remove filter from store

> var store = Ext.getCmp('gridPanel').getStore();
>
> store.removeFilter(store.filters.items[0]);

Extjs Doc has state that:

> Removes an individual Filter from the current filter set using the
> passed Filter/Filter id and by default, applies the updated filter set
> to the Store's unfiltered dataset.

Please refer [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-removeFilter).